# Reference Needed: Krull Dimension equals Minkowski Dimension

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis, krull-dimension, real-algebraic-geometry

I'm looking for a reference that basically states that the Krull dimension of an algebraic set in $\mathbb{R}$ equals the Minkowski dimension of the set.

It is common knowledge that the Krull dimension equals "The maximal dimension of the tangent vector spaces at the nonsingular points of V", however I couldn't even find reference to this this fact.

Also, to avoid singularities I prefer a statement that links the Minkowski dimension to the Krull dimension.

Comment: A real algebraic set of dimension $d$ has a nonsingular Zariski-open subset, which has the topology of a smooth $d$-manifold.  (I would expect the text of Bochnak, Coste and Roy to have a proof of this.)  This enables a simple inductive argument, if I am not mistaken.  (I assume that by the "Minkowski dimension" you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension, and without thinking much about that, I am taking it as obvious that $d$-submanifolds of Euclidean space have Minkowski dimension $d$.)